# React Typescript: Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a boolean stored in state, and I simply want to show or hide part of the dom if the value of `myBoolean` is true or false

```
const { global } = useContext(globalContext);
...
return (
 {global.myBoolean (
   <p>Show me if true</p>
)}
)
```

the error im getting is

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use conditional rendering,

```
{global.myBoolean && <p>Show me if true</p>}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to write it as this,

```
return (
 {global.myBoolean && (
  <p>Show me if true</p>
 )}
)
```

Hope it helps